# Cannot alter procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

When I run to alter the procedure, I get an error:

> Msg 18487, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   Login failed for user 'tester'.  Reason: The password of the account has expired.

However when I check under Security -> Logins, I can't find a user with this name.

I also tried removing the expiration with the following command:

```
ALTER LOGIN tester 
   WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master], 
        DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [us_english], 
        CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF
```

The system says that the user does not exist or I don't have permission (I'm sysadmin)

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot alter the login 'tester', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: There is no requirement that a login and user have the same name.

Comment: Is the proc hitting a remote server?  Is the linked server using `tester` as credentials?  Could it exist and be expired on the remote server?

Comment: You could have deleted the user from the server but not the DB, or created it on the server but not the DB. Check both locations for that user.

Comment: @JiggsJedi Yes, you were right, there was a user on the remote server. Thanks.

Comment: I have added this as an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment...

Please verify that the stored procedure is not utilising a linked server which may contain/use the credentials indicated.

Stored procedures validate connections/credentials on recompile.